# Kotlin Multiplatform Expected Annotations Returns `This class does not have a constructor` with neo4j actual typealias

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I have a multiplatform project with a modal class, User.
User.kt

```
class User {
    val id = -1
    val username = ""
    val age = -1
    val nickname = ""
}
```

I also have expected and actual annotations

Annotation.kt [Common Module]

```
expect annotation class NodeEntity
expect annotation class Id
expect annotation class GeneratedValue
```

More over, I have their actual implementation

Annotation.kt [JVM Module]

```
actual typealias ValueFor = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.ValueFor

actual typealias NodeEntity = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.NodeEntity

actual typealias Id = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Id

actual typealias GeneratedValue = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.GeneratedValue

actual typealias Relationship = org.neo4j.ogm.annotation.Relationship
```

I then went back and annotated my User.kt

```
@NodeEntity
class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    val id = -1
    val username = ""
    val age = -1
    val nickname = ""
}
```

But When I compile it, I get this error

```
Task :compileKotlinJvm FAILED
e: ...User.kt: (13, 2): This class does not have a constructor
e: ...User.kt: (21, 6): This class does not have a constructor
e: ...User.kt: (22, 6): This class does not have a constructor
```

What Am I doing wrong?

N:B. Attempts done

- Made the expected annotations have a constructor [no success]
- Made the expected annotations match with a constructor [ERROR: Parameter ''{0}'' has conflicting values in the expected and actual annotation]

FYI: My build.gradle already has the noArg in place, so that the User.kt class is compiled with a no argument public constructor

Answer (score 5):

Your expect annotations probably need explicit parenthesis.

```
expect annotation class SharedImmutable()
```

```
actual typealias SharedImmutable = kotlin.native.SharedImmutable
```

https://github.com/touchlab/Stately/blob/4b17057ad5d55f51f4ccf971cf79e51585ad2324/src/commonMain/kotlin/co/touchlab/stately/annotation/Annotations.kt#L26

Comment: To epand on this a bit, i know you said "Made the expected annotations have a constructor [no success]", but that's what the error seems to be complaining about. You may have another error after that as well

Answer (score 4):

I experienced a similar issue, but seemingly like the OP, I already included the explicit parenthesis. My particular issue had to do with the Java Library, in the Java Source Set, not being available to another Gradle Sub-project that was depending on it.

**TL;DR**

Assert that you are properly exposing the platform-specific dependencies. For instance, properly using `implementation` and `api` in the `build.gradle` files.

**Elaborating on my scenario**

I had a Gradle multi-project build:

```
Project
    AppSubProject
    LibrarySubProject
```

Where `AppSubProject` depended on `LibrarySubProject`. Both Gradle Sub-projects were Kotlin Multi-platform Modules.

In `LibrarySubProject`, there was an exposed Annotation Class:

**Common Source Set:**

```
expect annotation class Inject()
```

**JVM Source Set:**

```
actual typealias Inject = javax.inject.Inject
```

The Kotlin Common `Inject` annotation was available to `AppSubProject` since it depended on the `LibrarySubProject`.

**AppSubProject/build.gradle:**

```
...

commonMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(":LibrarySubProject")

...
```

**The Cause of the Issue**

In the `LibrarySubProject/build.gradle` file I wasn't exposing the JVM dependency:

```
...

jvmMain {
    dependencies {
        implementation "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
...
```

As you can see, I was using `implementation` instead of `api`. So when I used the annotation on a constructor of a class in `AppSubProject`:

```
class Example @Inject constructor()
```

and when I built the `AppSubProject`, it couldn't resolve the JVM dependency, and was cryptically giving me the following error:

```
e: Example.kt: This class does not have a constructor
```

**The Solution**

The solution was simply to expose the JVM dependency so that it could be resolved in the other module. So changing the `implementation` to `api` resolved the issue.

```
...

jvmMain {
    dependencies {
        api "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"
...
```

**Summation**

If you experience this issue, assert the following:

- The Kotlin Common Annotation Class explicitly provides the constructor parenthesis as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54130436/1478764)
- All necessary platform-specific dependencies are exposed properly